# Match the same pattern n times on the same line using sed

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have an input file *div.txt* that looks like this:

```
<div>a</div>b<div>c</div>
<div>d</div>
```

Now I want to pick all the *div* tags and the text between them using *sed*:

```
sed -n 's:.*\(<div>.*</div>\).*:\1:p' < div.txt
```

The result I get:

```
<div>c</div>
<div>d</div>
```

What I really want:

```
<div>a</div>
<div>c</div>
<div>d</div>
```

So the question is, how to match the same pattern n times on the same line?
(do not suggest me to use perl or python, please)

Comment: It's much safer to use HTML-aware tools to process HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(<\/div>\)[^<]*/\1\n/;/^</P;D' file
```

Replace a `</div>` followed by zero or more characters that are not a `<` by itself and a newline. Print only lines that begin with a `<`.

Comment: How about a text between tags which is on a different line than surrounding tags?

Comment: @RendoJack the solution is based on the data you provided. If there are corner cases please amend the question and supply them.

Answer (score 0):

Sed is not the right tool to handle HTML.

But if you really insist, and you know your input will always have properly closed pairs of div tags, you can just replace everything that's not inside a div by a newline:

```
sed 's=</div>.*<div>=</div>\n<div>='
```